# Magento - Display no. of day needed for Fedex shipping methods

Tags: magento-1.7, fedex

In Magento application, we use Fedex for shipping. We offer the following as allowed methods:

```
1. Home Delivery
2. Express Saver
3. 2Day
3. 2Day AM
4. Standard Overnight
```

It displayed correctly.

But now we want to display the no. of days needed for Home Delivery and Express Saver, i.e. we would like to display:

```
1. Home Delivery (2 - 3 Working Days)
2. Express saver (1 - 2 Working Days)
```

How can we do this?

Comment: Display the actual shipping times for Home Delivery and Express Saver

Comment: I mean that how many days needed for home delivery

ie. I want to display as 

`Home Delivery (2 - 3 Working Days)

Express saver (1 - 2 Working Days)`

Answer (score 2):

Go to *app/code/core/Mage/Usa/Model/Shipping/Carrier/Fedex.php*

around line 738 you've got all the methods and their labels.

```
$codes = array(
        'method' => array(
            'EUROPE_FIRST_INTERNATIONAL_PRIORITY' => Mage::helper('usa')->__('Europe First Priority'),
            'FEDEX_1_DAY_FREIGHT'                 => Mage::helper('usa')->__('1 Day Freight'),
            'FEDEX_2_DAY_FREIGHT'                 => Mage::helper('usa')->__('2 Day Freight'),
            'FEDEX_2_DAY'                         => Mage::helper('usa')->__('2 Day'),
            'FEDEX_2_DAY_AM'                      => Mage::helper('usa')->__('2 Day AM'),
            'FEDEX_3_DAY_FREIGHT'                 => Mage::helper('usa')->__('3 Day Freight'),
            'FEDEX_EXPRESS_SAVER'                 => Mage::helper('usa')->__('Express Saver'),
            'FEDEX_GROUND'                        => Mage::helper('usa')->__('Ground'),
            'FIRST_OVERNIGHT'                     => Mage::helper('usa')->__('First Overnight'),
            'GROUND_HOME_DELIVERY'                => Mage::helper('usa')->__('Home Delivery'),
            'INTERNATIONAL_ECONOMY'               => Mage::helper('usa')->__('International Economy'),
            'INTERNATIONAL_ECONOMY_FREIGHT'       => Mage::helper('usa')->__('Intl Economy Freight'),
            'INTERNATIONAL_FIRST'                 => Mage::helper('usa')->__('International First'),
            'INTERNATIONAL_GROUND'                => Mage::helper('usa')->__('International Ground'),
            'INTERNATIONAL_PRIORITY'              => Mage::helper('usa')->__('International Priority'),
            'INTERNATIONAL_PRIORITY_FREIGHT'      => Mage::helper('usa')->__('Intl Priority Freight'),
            'PRIORITY_OVERNIGHT'                  => Mage::helper('usa')->__('Priority Overnight'),
            'SMART_POST'                          => Mage::helper('usa')->__('Smart Post'),
            'STANDARD_OVERNIGHT'                  => Mage::helper('usa')->__('Standard Overnight'),
            'FEDEX_FREIGHT'                       => Mage::helper('usa')->__('Freight'),
            'FEDEX_NATIONAL_FREIGHT'              => Mage::helper('usa')->__('National Freight'),
        ),
```

so for Express Saver it would be:

```
=> Mage::helper('usa')->__('Express saver (1 - 2 Working Days)'),
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using web services you can do a 'rate quote' transaction and you should get time in transit for that zipcode returned for ground and of course the 'express services' are self explainitory. Hope this helps.